# sockets.io emit messages are delayed till post is finished

Tags: sockets, post, express, socket.io, multer

I am uploading a file (using multer) and doing some processing on it and i want to show progress while i am working on it. my issue is that the client receives all the updates after the processing is finished. so the progress bar goes from 0 to 100% instead of incrementally updating as the code progresses.

The server side

```
var multer  = require('multer')
var uploading = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })


app.post('/result', uploading.single('audio'), function(req, res) {
    var oldPath = req.file.path;
    var newPath = req.file.destination + req.file.originalname;
    fs.renameSync(oldPath, newPath)
    var ext = newPath.substring(newPath.length-3);
    io.emit('message',{'message': 'upload completed !'});
    console.log('1st update');
    if (ext =='mp3' || ext == 'wav')
    {
        //console.log('running audio code');
        io.emit('update',{'step': 'Converting Audio',percent: 2/10});
        audio_code(newPath );
        //res.render('Results_Audio', { });
    }
    else if (ext =='avi' || ext == 'mp4')
    {
        console.log('run video code');
        res.render('Results_Video', { });
    }
});
```

on the client side

```
socket.on('update',function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        Update(data);});

    function Update(data){
        document.getElementById('NameArea').innerHTML = data.step;
        console.log(data.percent*100);
        document.getElementById('ProgressBar').style.width = data.percent*100 + '%';
        document.getElementById('percent').innerHTML = (Math.round((data.percent*100))) + '%';
        }
```

Comment: I am new to this so i might be missing a simple concept

Comment: How are you posting the data?  Can you show that code?  My guess is that is a blocking call

Comment: @greg_diesel i am using multer i've added that info in the question

Comment: How long does `audio_code(newPath );` take to run?

Comment: It takes a few minutes depending on the size of the uploaded file
that's why i am emiting the update message to show what step the code is at and how much is done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. switching from socket to primus showed me that since my code was a bit computationally intensive and running synchronously it blocked the server for a time long enough for the websocket to timeout and close. so all i had to do is increase the time allowed for the server to respond to the ping pong check before timing out.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as your post hits the server it will run the block

`app.post('/result', uploading.single('audio'), function(req, res) {
...
}`

Which means you will immediately get

> io.emit('message',{'message': 'upload completed !'});
>
> io.emit('update',{'step': 'Converting Audio',percent: 2/10});

Then you wait while this runs

> audio_code(newPath );

Nothing is output.
then when audio_code completes you will get
to the finish.

Are you emitting any progress inside of `audio_code` ?  If not then that's why you get no progress increments.

Comment: Actually the upload complete emit and the update emit are received after the code is finished along with the update emits sent inside the audio code.
I should also say that any emits sent from either side are received  timely before the file is posted